# Always show hamburger menu in materializecss

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

How can I always display the menu icon on navbar materializecss? Like when clicked, the drawer appears and hides vice versa.

Html:

```
<nav class="default" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">Brand</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect red waves-light btn">Sign up</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

JS:

```
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
      menuWidth: 300, // Default is 240
      edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
      closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At line,

`<a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>`, add one more class `.show-on-large`.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/3maohcLk/)**

**For more info : [Full Screen HTML Structure](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html)**

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question.